# Complex join in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have two models: ProgramStudent and StudentCheckIn (a student can have many class check ins, so StudentCheckIn belongs_to ProgramStudent).  A ProgramStudent has a date_of_rank Date column that indicates when they attained their current rank.

I want to generate a query that identifies all ProgramStudents that have more than X check-ins since their date_of_rank.

The StudentCheckIn model has this scope:

```
scope :since, -> (date) { where("checked_in_at >= ?", date) }
```

I can construct a query that merges this scope as follows:

```
ProgramStudent.joins(:student_check_ins)
    .merge(StudentCheckIn.since(Date.today - 2.months))
    .group("program_students.id")
    .having("count(*) > ?", 15)
```

which generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT "program_students".* FROM "program_students" 
INNER JOIN "student_check_ins" 
ON "student_check_ins"."program_student_id" = "program_students"."id" 
WHERE (checked_in_at >= '2016-02-12') 
GROUP BY program_students.id 
HAVING count(*) > 15
```

and that will return all ProgramStudents who have more than 15 check-ins since a fixed date (in this case, two months ago), but I want the query to use the individual ProgramStudent's date_of_rank, not a fixed date.  Is there a way to do this with ActiveRecord?  If not, how would this be done with raw SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the SQL you're aiming for:

```
SELECT "program_students".* FROM "program_students" 
INNER JOIN "student_check_ins" 
ON "student_check_ins"."program_student_id" = "program_students"."id" 
WHERE (checked_in_at >= "program_students"."date_of_rank") 
GROUP BY program_students.id, program_students.date_of_rank 
HAVING count(*) > 15
```

I doubt your `since` scope could take a column name, since any string input would probably get escaped, but you could just put the `where` clause in the final ARel:

```
ProgramStudent.joins(:student_check_ins).
  where("student_check_ins.checked_in_at >= program_students.date_of_rank").
  group("program_students.id, program_students.date_of_rank").
  having("count(*) > ?", 15)
```